# java string split query

Tags: java

I am having a brain freeze - I am running the following (split on string in java - trying to separate the characters around "|").  The split command is giving me an array of individual characters instead of the the values around the '|' character.  Any helpful suggestions would be most welcome.  For instance, in the case below, I am trying to retrieve "abc", "123456789" and "def" in three different array locations.

```
//testKey is the following "abc|123456789|def"
String[] keySplit = testKey.split("|");
//I am getting null in keySplit[0] & "a" in keySplit[1]
```

Comment: To the downvoters - get a life!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)** uses a regular expression. Also, the pipe operator`|` is a special character in regular expressions (meaning *OR*). Therefore, you need to escape that character here:

```
String[] keySplit = testKey.split("\\|");
```

Comment: By the time I opened a new tab with just popped up question, there was already your answer. Can you be even more faster? ;) Just one clarification -> Did you posted the answer before the question?

Comment: +1 for Reimeus - thanks it worked.  I'll accept the answer after 12 minutes (SO restriction)